# Disable logs for existing containers in docker

Tags: linux, docker

I am new to docker and am running an Ubuntu container on Arch linux. I use it for debugging and building software with an older version of gcc. I was running low on disk and stumbled upon logs which I was able to truncate. I don't need the logs but don't want to loose my existing container that I created some time back. The solutions I have come across (disable through drivers or set rotate size to 0m) are in my understanding applied to create new containers, but I want to apply them to existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an image of that container with [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/), remove the container with [docker rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) and then use `--log=none` option to [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#logging-drivers-log-driver).

If you're new to Docker, consider that it's best to use ephemeral containers of a given image.  You can also maintain a Dockerfile to recreate that image with [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, seems like a good solution. I will come back when I test it.